# How to return a recordset as an output parameter?

Tags: c#, t-sql, ado.net

I am calling a stored procedure that should delete a record. Before deleting, a check is performed if there are any records in another table that refer to the record we want to delete. If yes, I need to return a list of text values that would identify records that refer to the record we want to delete, so the user could delete them first. I guess I should use an output parameter for this, but not sure how to assign a recordset to it. Here is my code:

```
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DeleteTD", conn);

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pID", gvTD.SelectedDataKey));
            SqlParameter resultParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pResult", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
            resultParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

I am not sure my resultParameter is correct.
Here is part of the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteTD
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @pID INT, 
    @pResult NVARCHAR(100) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here

    DECLARE @vCount INT;

    SELECT @pResult = 0;
    SELECT @vCount = COUNT(1) FROM Город WHERE Город.ТД = '@pID';

    IF @vCount > 0
        SELECT @pResult = Название FROM Город WHERE ТД = '@pID';
    ELSE
        DELETE FROM ТД WHERE ID = @pID;
```

Again, I am not sure what type @pResult should have.

Could you please help me to write my code the right way?
Thanks,
David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the SP at the moment is that you are only going to get a single return value as opposed to a list of values.

You have three choices:

1) Return 1 value to the user indicating the first record with a problem. This is the easiest to implement.

```
 SELECT TOP 1 @pResult = Название FROM Город WHERE ТД = '@pID';
```

In this case, @pResult should be the size of Название.

2) Return all values to the user indicating the complete list of problems in a parameter. This will become a problem both for the SQL and for the user if there are too many values.

```
 SELECT @pResult = CASE WHEN @pResult <> '' THEN ', ' ELSE '' END + Название FROM Город WHERE ТД = '@pID';
```

This will return a comma-delimited list. In this case @pResult should be NVARCHAR(MAX) if your DB supports it or NVARCHAR(8000). In either case, you should probably think about limiting this statement to the top n (say 10 matches).

3) Return all values to the user using a standard select statement.

```
 SELECT Название FROM Город WHERE ТД = '@pID';
```

In this case, your code will have to ExecuteReader instead of ExecuteNonQuery and there will be no need for @pResult.

As for the correct method to work with @pResult:

For the first two options, change the following line:

```
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

to:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

string sError;
if (resultParameter.Value != DBNull.Value) {
    sError = resultParameter.Value.ToString();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sError) {
  // Report the error to the user.
```

In the third case, you will eliminate the parameter code altogether and just process the reader output (rough code follows):

```
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

StringBuilder sbResult = new StringBuilder(500);

do while rdr.Read() {
   if (sbResult.Length != 0) {
      sbResult.Append(", ");
   }
   sbResult.Append(rdr[0].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would consider getting rid of @pResult.

Change it to a statement that ...

if count > 0
select ids from the other table where it = @pId

else
do the delete
return null

then complete a check for null in your code .. otherwise you will have the list of records that are tied to @pId

Take Care,

Brynn

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I wish I could mark as Answer both yours and competent_tech's...